# Modify hosts file in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile with RUN instruction to modify /etc/hosts file but it doesn't work.

```
FROM dockerhub.mydomain.com/sometag/java8
MAINTAINER itsme

ADD some-java-app.jar app.jar
ADD hosts tmp/
ENV PATH=/opt/java/bin:$PATH
RUN cat /tmp/hosts >> /etc/hosts
CMD ["java",\
    "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom",\
    "-jar",\
    "/app.jar"]
```

In `hosts` file that is copied to /tmp in docker image there is a additional hosts names and IPs. I want to `cat` that `/tmp/hosts` to `/etc/hosts` but after building image `/etc/hosts` is unmodified.

How to modify this file properly?
EDIT:
I'm trying to use `tee` command but while image is build contents of `/tmp/hosts` is echoed to console, not to `/etc/hosts`.

```
RUN bash -c 'cat /tmp/hosts | tee -a /etc/hosts'
```

It looks like `|` or `>>` doesn't work in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Docker creates `/etc/hosts` file while container is started. That's why my modifications of `/etc/hosts` file are overwritten. I can change hosts file dynamically, via CMD command.

```
FROM dockerhub.mydomain.com/sometag/java8
MAINTAINER itsme

ADD some-java-app.jar app.jar
ADD hosts tmp/
ENV PATH=/opt/java/bin:$PATH
CMD cat /tmp/hosts >> /etc/hosts; java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar; cat /etc/hosts
```

Last commands shows changes made by first command in CMD row.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to import a file you should use the `copy` function and not `add` - add if you are getting from a URL or importing an archive.

docker gives this as an example:

```
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/
RUN pip install --requirement /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY . /tmp/
```

so in your example, this should work

```
COPY hosts /tmp/
ENV PATH=/opt/java/bin:$PATH
RUN cat /tmp/hosts >> /etc/hosts
```

Comment: But hosts file is added to image. Problem is in adding new content to /etc/hosts file.

Comment: so the host file is in /tmp but is not appended to /etc/hosts, or, you are trying to overwrite file 'host' in /tmp  ?

Comment: I'm trying to append content.

Comment: yes that's understood, but which part is not working, the copy or the append?

Comment: Like I said before cat /tmp/hosts >> /etc/hosts not append contents of /tmp/hosts to /etc/hosts.

Comment: so log into the container and run this command: 'cat /tmp/hosts >> /etc/hosts'  - what happens?

Comment: I think you have no file called 'host' in temp, as I point out in the answer, use this "COPY hosts /tmp/" - not this 'ADD hosts tmp/'

Comment: From command line content of /tmp/hosts is added to /etc/hosts, but not from Dockerfile.
No, you wrong. File exists in /tmp. There is no matter which command I use, COPY or ADD.